# Differentiate between fragment interface and background service?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-service

I have a method in a service file, its role is to check if there is a new update in my server or not.. this method is called from two places .. it is called automatically when the app starts and its called manually from a fragment interface.
What I want is -> when the method called from the user interface I want to display an alert in some exceptions instead of writing them in my log file.

This is my service method:

```
public void checkUpdate(Boolean IsUpdateExist,Boolean IsServerError,String LatestApplicationCode,
                        String LatestApplicationName,Integer LatestVersionCode,String LatestVersionName,
                        String ResponseUpdateInformationType,String ResponseUpdateURI,String ServerErrorMessage,String ServerErrorStackTrace){

    if(IsServerError == null){
        //If called from a user interface => show alert dialog here.

        FileUtil.logInformation(this.getClass().getName(), "Can't connect to server!");
        return;
    }

    else{
        if(IsServerError){
        //If called from a user interface => show alert dialog here.

            FileUtil.logInformation(this.getClass().getName(), "Server error! | error message: "+ServerErrorMessage);
            return;
        }
        else {
            if(!IsUpdateExist || IsUpdateExist == null){
            //If called from a user interface => show alert dialog here.

                FileUtil.logInformation(this.getClass().getName(), "No updates available !");
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (LatestVersionCode != null && LatestVersionCode <= CurrentVersionCode){
               //If called from a user interface => show alert dialog here.

                    FileUtil.logInformation(this.getClass().getName(), "No new updates ! | version in the server= "+LatestVersionCode
                            +" version installed= "+CurrentVersionCode);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    if(ResponseUpdateURI != null && !ResponseUpdateURI.contentEquals("")){
                        this.updateApp(IsUpdateExist,IsServerError,LatestApplicationCode,LatestApplicationName,LatestVersionCode,
                                LatestVersionName,ResponseUpdateInformationType,ResponseUpdateURI,ServerErrorMessage,ServerErrorStackTrace);
                    }
                    else {
                    //If called from a user interface => show alert dialog here.

                        FileUtil.logInformation(this.getClass().getName(), "It seems there is a problem with the download URL");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write an interface that both your `Service` and `Fragment` implements it and then you check the instance of that class, and do whatever you need to. Eg:

```
interface MyCustomJobExecutor {}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyCustomJobExecutor {/*...*/}

public class MyService extends Service implements MyCustomJobExecutor {
    //...
    public void checkUpdate(MyCustomJobExecutor jobExecutor, ...) {
        if (jobExecutor instanceof MyFragment) {
            // Manual code execution here
        } else { // Automatic code execution stuff }
    }
    //...
}
```